# Why do clients broadcast an endorsed transation instead of the peers doing it themselves?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, concept

I have a conceptual question. The normal transaction lifecycle involves:

1. A client sending a transaction to a few peers.
2. The peers simulate it and endorse it. The endorsement is sent back to the client.
3. The client upon receiving the endorsement, broadcasts it to the ordering service.

Why do we have the extra overhead of the peers sending the endorsement back to the client? Why can't they just directly send it back to the ordering service?

Answer (score 1):

1. The peers would need to know about each other and decide which peer is sending the transaction to the orderer.
2. There are typically much more clients than peers, so the idea is to free resources from the peer so it won't have to worry about the lifecycle of the transaction (in case the orderer that received the transaction crashed, etc.).

There is a new feature in Fabric called the ["Gateway service"](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-rfcs/text/0000-fabric-gateway.html) which lets a client collaborate with a peer and the peer orchestrates the endorsement collection for the client.